# Setting the Search Path... global setting in MacVim

Tags: macos, vim, macvim, ctags

Noticed an interesting GUI based setting in MacVim, that seems useful but I can't seem to find any official word on what it does exactly.

It is located at **Edit** Menu **> Global Settings > Search Path...**

Once there a dialog drops down with the following:

> "Enter search path for files"
>
> Separate directory names with a comma.

```
.,/usr/include,,
```

From that editable line I get the clue that this appears to be a header search path. Something I would hope works with ctags, etc. But the setting I put in there don't seem to stick between open and closing just MacVim windows with out even quitting the MacVim Application.

Searing Vim help only really turns up new-search-path which I am not sure how to use or set if it is even related?

Is this what I think it is? The header search path. If yes then how do I set the path in my .vimrc or where needed so that the changes to it are persistent.

If this is not a header search path then what does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are right about its purpose, the setting is simply called `path`: its default value (`:set path?`) is `.,/usr/include,,` just as in your question.

You can use it to tell Vim to look for files in specific places.